# JPA 2.1 Schema gereration problems

Tags: java, eclipselink, database-schema, derby, jpa-2.1

I'm trying to use pure JPA 2.1 as a standardized way to generate db schema.
(Underlying database - Derby embedded,  persistence provider - eclipseLink)

To check generated scripts I set `<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation-target" value="database-and-scripts"/>`
And as a result I got it with some 'sequence' table within.
And although ... `ERROR 42X05: Table/View 'SEQUENCE' does not exist.`

Can somebody help to understand such a weird behavior?

maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <version>10.9.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Entity:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
// getters/setters/constructors
}
```

main body:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("chapter04PU");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
tx.begin();
em.persist(new Book("Neuromancer"));
tx.commit();

em.close();
emf.close();
```

persistence-unit:

```
<persistence-unit name="chapter04PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

    <class>Book</class>
    <properties>
        <!--<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>-->
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation-action" value="drop-and-create"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation-target" value="database-and-scripts"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target" value="create.sql"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.drop-target" value="delete.sql"/>

    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby:chapter04DB;create=true"/>
</properties>
```

generated script file:

```
CREATE TABLE BOOK (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, TITLE VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (ID))
CREATE TABLE SEQUENCE (SEQ_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, SEQ_COUNT DECIMAL(15), PRIMARY KEY (SEQ_NAME))
INSERT INTO SEQUENCE(SEQ_NAME, SEQ_COUNT) values ('SEQ_GEN', 0)
```

---

**Update**
After replacing:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation-action" value="drop-and-create"/>
```

with:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
```

I can 'normally' run app (with exit code 0).

***But*** I still take this weird message while first run (with absent DB).

[image]
the second run is clear - no such messages.

Comment: Found! Should replace: <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation-action" value="drop-and-create"/> with <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>

Comment: And now I still get this error but not through the System.err O_o and "Process finished with exit code 0"

Comment: Are you saying you have figured out your problem? Or that the behavior has changed? What error, precisely, are you trying to resolve?

Comment: The main problem seems to be solved, but I still have some strange behavior (post updated).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your suggestion to use `<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>`!

As for the second problem, the main culprit here is `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` which probably was a default value provided by IDE on entity creation. Given the way `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider` processes this annotation (leading to the exception about non-existant 'SEQUENCE' table), the simplest solution would be to just use `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)` instead.